# How to find c in the equation.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Consider the function $f(x) = \sqrt
{16 + x}$. Notice that $f(x) = c \sqrt{1 + x/16}$
for some constant $c$. How to find $c$? can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Is the equation $$\sqrt{16+x}=c\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{16}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Factor out $16$ from the radicand

$$\sqrt{16+x} = \sqrt{16(1+x/16)} = \sqrt{16}\sqrt{1+x/16}$$

Comment: Is this the value of C